# ActiveRecord: find a record that has an association with a certain value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following association:

```
ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model_b
end

ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_as
end
```

Let's say there's model_a.foo and model_b.bar columns, and there are multiple ModelA records that have the same foo value (let's say x). However only one ModelA has an associated ModelB with a bar value of y. I think the SQL would be:

```
SELECT model_a.id FROM model_a LEFT JOIN model_b ON model_a.id = model_b.model_a_id WHERE model_a.foo = "x" AND model_b.bar = "y"
```

How can I write that using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be very protective of this particular snippet of your codebase!

```
ModelA.joins(
  'left join model_bs on model_as.id = model_bs.model_a_id'
).where(
  model_a: { foo: 'x' }, 
  model_b: { bar: 'y' }
).select(
  'model_as.id'
)
```

Because you want a left join which cannot be implemented with a simple `join(:model_b)` is the reason for the lengthy `left join model_bs on model_as.id = model_bs.model_a_id`.  The where method parameters is hash based to show you an example of how they can be used.  The final `select` method call is to select the desired `model_as.id`, assuming your table names are `model_as` and `model_bs`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: haha yes, the names have been changed to protect the innocent :) perfect thanks so much!